# Sending object to method in another class on event

Tags: c#, wpf, events

In my second window, on double click I want to call a method in my MainWindow and send it an object.

Everything worked just fine when the second window was Owned by the MainWindow, but that caused MainWindow to always be drawn behind the second which is not what I wanted.

So my question is, how on earth do I call my `public LoadSong(Song tempSong)` method in my MainWindow on button click in my second window (assuming that I cannot directly call the method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat. Below two examples.

**First Approach**

Simple approach without any external libraries would be to create a custom even on the child window and subscribe to it from parent. Also you can propagate an object this way.

The object to propagate:

```
public class MyCommunicationObject
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And then the child window:

```
public partial class ChildWindow : Window
{
    public event Action<MyCommunicationObject> MyChildWindowEvent;

    public ChildWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myObject = new MyCommunicationObject();
        myObject.Message = "Hello from Child Window";
        this.MyChildWindowEvent(myObject);
    }
}
```

Clicking the button will propagate the MyChildWindowEvent event.

In the main window you have to subscribe for the event when you create the child dialog (in my example I'm doing that on button click because that's when the window is created).

The main window code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var childWindow = new ChildWindow();
    childWindow.MyChildWindowEvent += ChildWindow_MyChildWindowEvent;
    childWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Second Approach**

Or as suggested above use an `EventAggregator`. You can use for instance Prism. You will have to install it using NuGet manager. Once it's installed it Allows you to use `EventAggregator` object. The object can propagate events that inherit from `PubSubEvent`, e.g.:

```
public class MyEvent : PubSubEvent<MyCommunicationObject>
{

}
```

The main window and child window have to share an instance of the `EventAggregator`. Then you have to subscribe for an event that's propagated by your child window. Assuming the object has been created in the main window below is an example how to subscribe and handle the event on the main window (again on button click):

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var childWindow = new AnotherChildWindow(eventAggregator);

    eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Subscribe(obj =>
    {
        this.myTextBox2.Text = obj.Message;
    });

    childWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

And the child window has to publish the event (together with the object that's used for communication):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myObject = new MyCommunicationObject();
    myObject.Message = "Hello from another child window";
    this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Publish(myObject);
}
```

Here on the child window the instance of the `EventAggregator` comes from the main window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or other [event-based patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745866.aspx).

First create new event with property of your object type to send it between components.

Next subscribe MainWindow to your event and call LoadSong in event handler with parameter received from handler parameter.

Finally raise (or publish in other terms) your event from your second window on double click event handler.

As you can see both of implementations is a part of MVVM libraries and [this pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) can be useful for your app.